# 'no identity found' when using gradle to exec codesign

Tags: java, macos, gradle, codesign

I am trying to sign my Java/JavaFX application using codesign with gradle. My gradle code is as following:

```
exec {
  val codeSignArgs = listOf("-s", "'${macSigningKeyDeveloperIdApp}'", "--timestamp", "--options", "runtime", "--entitlements", "../../../entitlements.plist", "--deep", "-f", "--verbose", "UTMCoordinateConverter.app")
  logger.quiet("code sign args: $codeSignArgs")
  workingDir = macRel
  isIgnoreExitValue = true
  executable = codeSignTool.absolutePath
  args(codeSignArgs)
}
```

Where `codeSignTool` is `/usr/bin/codesign` and `macRel` is the directory where the `app` file is, and `macSigningKeyDeveloperIdApp` is my signing developer id.

Gradle gives me the following output:

```
> Task :codeSign
Inside codeSign
code sign args: [-s, 'Developer ID Application: Victor Ewert (XXXXXXXXXX)', --timestamp, --options, runtime, --entitlements, ../../../entitlements.plist, --deep, -f, --verbose, UTMCoordinateConverter.app]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
'Developer ID Application: Victor Ewert (XXXXXXXXXX)': no identity found
2:38:26 p.m.: Task execution finished 'codeSign'.
```

The strange thing is, I can run the (equivalent) command fine, from the command line using:

```
/usr/bin/codesign -s 'Developer ID Application: Victor Ewert (XXXXXXXXX)' --timestamp --options runtime --entitlements ../../../entitlements.plist --deep -f --verbose UTMCoordinateConverter.app
```

run from the location of the `app` file.

I have double and triple checked my Developer ID, and it looks fine (checked using `security find-identity -p codesigning -v login.keychain`. I have also made sure my login keychain is unlocked. I don't think it is a problem with my Developer ID.

I'm guessing it has something to do with how gradle is executing the command, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't; are you seeing the same problem? My 'solution' was to create the signing task using Ant, and then call the Ant task from Gradle. Not ideal, but it works.